# Can we give boost to fields through solr config file?

Tags: solr

Every time we mention in query to give boost. Is it possible to mention boost for any field name in solr config itself ?

Answer (score 0):

in the requestHandler config :

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
....
<lst name="appends">
     <str name="qf">my_col^1</str>
     <!--str name="qf">my_col^boost_val</str-->
     <!--str name="bq">my_col2^boost_val</str-->
</lst>
....
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to individually boost fields in Solr.
There is an additional parameter **qf (Query Fields)** which introduce list of fields, each of which is assigned a boost factor to increase or decrease that particular field's importance in the query.
Below is the sample solrconfig.

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="defType">dismax</str>
  <str name="qf">title^10 content^5</str>
</lst>
</requestHandler>
```

In above qf assigns title field a boost of 10 and content a boost of 5.

**NOTE** :- The qf (Query Fields) Parameter can't be used with the standard query parser. You can use it with the dismax or edismax query parser.